# What is a thread-safe List implementation that allows Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting, collections, concurrency

I have to write a program that requires a list. This list needs to be thread-safe in its implementation (mostly to avoid ConcurrentModificationException) but ALSO needs to allow the 
`Collections.sort()` method to be applied, for API reasons.

CopyOnWriteArrayList fulfills the former, but not the latter, and other implementations I can find allow the latter but not the former.

Does Java have a list implementation that will work for me?

EDIT: An important point to note is that unfortunately my code needs to be Java 6 compatible.

Comment: Is using 3rd party libraries an option?

Comment: @Fildor if they are otherwise light-weight,it could be.

Comment: Would [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) be a candidate? Nevermind - just read your comment about the API calling explicitly `Collections.sort()` :(

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that hierarchically speaking that's an implementation of Set, not of List.

Comment: use singleton that exposes `add()/delete()/sort()/getList()/clearList()` methods. some of these methods should be synchronized, and other methods should have flag to allow or not allow the operation (like sort) can't work unless no add/del is being called. you may use some boolean flags to handle this

Comment: I've been considering Vector, which helps, but only allows relatively atomic operations to be performed in a concurrency-safe manner. Sort is not among these, as it does not give out object-locks to Collections (nor, why would it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, CopyOnWriteArrayList locks the entire collection (for insertion) while sorting. No?

Looks like you are good with CopyOnWriteArrayList. Below is the snippet from this class -

```
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();**
    try {
        Object[] elements = getArray();
        Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, elements.length);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") E[] es = (E[])newElements;
        Arrays.sort(es, c);
        setArray(newElements);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Hmm.... since you've updated the question that code needs to be Java6 compatible, I'd  say that you should extend the normal list and make use of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html. In this type of lock, readers are not blocked from reading even when some other thread has acquired writeLock already, and 2 threads can acquire 'read' lock simultaneously.

Btw, this technique will require your caller to know that Collection.sort(...) shouldn't be called since you will have to expose explicit sort() method on your list. Hmm.... not sure if this was helpful.

Comment: Can you add a link to the source of this snippet?

Comment: Thats cool - this method was actually added with Java8; and I didn't knew about it yet. Great input!

Comment: Note also that in Java8, `Collections.sort(foo)` delegates to `List.sort(...)`, so you should be good calling that method also.

Comment: OP just added, code needs to be Java 6 compatible :(

Answer (score 4):

I am wondering if this actually possible on a conceptual level: for a *sort* operation to be consistent, I would expect that the **whole** list is blocked for any adds/removes while the sorting is going on.

But Collections.sort() has no idea that it would need to **lock** the whole list while doing its work. You give it a list, and if another thread is trying to modify the list at the same time ... good luck with that.

Or if you reverse the point of view: how should a "thread-safe" list understand that it is right now in the process of being sorted; so - some accesses (like swapping elements) are fine; but others (like adding/removing) elements are not?!

In other words: I think you can only do this: pick any of the "thread-safe" list implementations; and then you have to put **your own wrapper** in place that

1. "Locks" the list for changes
2. Does the sorting work
3. "Unlocks" the list

And of course, for "2."; you are free to turn to Collections.sort().

Or, if you are using Java8 - you use the CopyOnWriteArrayList and its already implemented sort() method (which is kind of proving my point: you can only do *proper sorting* if you **own** the list while running the sort operation!).

Giving your latest comment: of course, you could manually "backport" the Java8 version of CopyOnWriteArrayList into your environment and use that; but of course, that won't help; as I understand that Java6-Collections.sort() will **not** call the new sort() method from that class.

So, it seems that the sum of your requirements can't be resolved; and you will have to bite the bullet and doing most of that in your own code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the API implementation will specifically be trying to call Collections.sort() on it. I cannot change that. I'm also stuck with having to maintain a Java 6 compatible codebase.